# Scrolling Instagram Dialog Box

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, instagram

I am trying to make a Python code to make tho thing: Scrapes username X followers, and also all the users that liked a specific photo of X.
The problem is that I am facing an issue that will impact those 2 codes.

Right now I am working on the first part, that is scrape the followers. I am already able to get the first 12 usernames, the problem is that to get more users I would need to scroll the Instagram Followers Box down, but I cant manage to do that. Have already seem some codes here on the forum, but none of them seems to work for me.

This is what is done right now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -- coding: utf-8 --

import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/User/Desktop/chromedriver')

#login
username = ""  ##user
password = ""  ##pass
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']").submit()
time.sleep(4)

account = "vans"

link = 'https://www.instagram.com/' + account

driver.get(link)

driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("follower").click()
time.sleep(2)


html = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

followers = soup.find_all("a", class_='FPmhX notranslate _0imsa')

for user in followers:
    print(user.text)
```

So, if anyone could help me making
[these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0k2VN.png) dialog box scroll down untill the 12th username, it would be great. Actually, any type of scroll is already going to help me a lot.

Thx

Comment: FWIW: scraping instagram is a violation of their TOS and will (likely) get you blocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could inject javascript using seleniums execute_script(script)

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 420)")
```

Comment: also note that instagrams website is dynamically generated through react.js so those class names you're accessing might change, in their attempt to stop scraping

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in 2019...

```
FList = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[role=\'dialog\'] ul')
numberOfFollowersInList = len(FList.find_elements_by_css_selector('li'))

FList.click()
actionChain = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
time.sleep(random.randint(2,4))

while (numberOfFollowersInList < max):
    actionChain.key_down(Keys.SPACE).key_up(Keys.SPACE).perform()        
    numberOfFollowersInList = len(FList.find_elements_by_css_selector('li'))
    time.sleep(0.4)
    print(numberOfFollowersInList)
    actionChain.key_down(Keys.SPACE).key_up(Keys.SPACE).perform()            
    time.sleep(1)
```